# Bootstrap 5 media query not matching responsive class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 for a simple layout like this

```css
.section1 {
        background: red;
    }

@media all and (max-width: 575px) {

    .section1 {
        background: green !important;
    }

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

<div class="container1 d-flex d-sm-block">
 
    <div class="text-white section1">
        Section 1
    </div>

    <div class="bg-light text-dark section2">
        Section 2
    </div>

</div>

<div>
```

When making the screensize smaller, I want the background of `section1` to change to green at the same time that the display property of `container1` changes to display `flex`

Currently there are 3 different states..

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: So you want it to be the opposite of what you got right now?

Comment: No, there appears to be 3 different states, I expected there to be 2 so it has left me confused

Answer (score 0):

you should change "container1" class from :

> d-flex d-sm-block

to

> d-sm-flex d-block

and change media max width to `max-width: 1024px`

```css
.section1 {
        background: red;
    }

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {

    .section1 {
        background: green !important;
    }

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

<div class="container1 d-sm-flex d-block">
 
    <div class="text-white section1">
        Section 1
    </div>

    <div class="bg-light text-dark section2">
        Section 2
    </div>

</div>

<div>
```